# How do I use HAML to render JSON views in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, haml

I'd like to have my controller render json views, as .json.haml ... is this possible? What is the syntax like? 
Or would I need to use something else for JSON templating? such as http://inem.github.com/tequila.html?

Comment: If you render into haml you will then have to render THAT into html. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

HAML is intented for use to generate HTML markup.

If you need to render json, just call `render` passing `:json` as an option within your controller:

```
render :json => my_object
```

Or if you have a more complex data structure and/or require more flexibility try [JSON Builder](http://github.com/dewski/json_builder), it's a template engine for JSON, similar to the XML builder provided in Rails.